# conditionally return attributes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three attributes that I want to display on a page: `length`, `height`, and `width`.

If a fourth attribute (`variable_dimensions`) is set to true on the object (thus invalidating the need to enter data for the other attributes), I want to return a string that says "Dimensions variable." If `width` is nil, I want to return `length` x `height`. I want to return the full `length` x `height` x `width` otherwise.

I've attempted this as a helper.

```
module ItemsHelper
  def dimensions_available(length, height, width)
    if @item.variable_dimensions == true
      return "Dimensions variable"
    elseif width.nil?
      dimensions = length, height
      return dimensions
    else
      dimensions = length, height, width
      return dimensions
    end
  end
end
```

This works when `dimensions_variable` is set to true. It does what I want with the objects that have variable dimensions. In the other two cases it's printing to the page as an array that looks like [60.3, 35.4, nil] when `width` is nil, and [39, 45.3, 30.4] otherwise. How do I remove the array styling so that it it looks like 10cm x 30cm x 48cm? I previously attempted this with string interpolation, but was told that it's an anti-pattern.

Comment: Looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273038/check-if-variables-are-null-and-if-not-print) it's clear that you misunderstood what tadman was trying to tell you. String interpolation is not an antipattern. The specific construction `"#{x}"` (in which the string contains nothing other than a single `#{...}` interpolation expression) is an antipattern, because you're not interpolating `x` *with* anything—it's equivalent to `x.to_s`. `"#{x}cm x #{y}cm x #{z}cm"` is *not* an antipattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact), you could remove any `nil` dimension:

```
module ItemsHelper
  def dimensions_available(length, height, width)
    if @item.variable_dimensions
      "Dimensions variable"
    else
      [length, height, width].compact.map do |dim|
        "#{dim}cm"
      end.join(' x ')
    end
  end
end
```

Also, there's no need for `return` or `== true`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
module ItemsHelper
  def dimensions_available(length, height, width)
    if @item.variable_dimensions
      "Dimensions variable"
    elsif width.nil?
      "#{length}cm x #{height}cm"
    else
      "#{length}cm x #{height}cm x #{width}cm"
    end
  end
end
```